# Equal and Not Equal operators not working when filtering formula percent field in Salesforce SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a formula percent field on a custom object that I am trying to filter by.
The problem I have noticed is that when the formula is represented as a number field on the custom object I can't filter using the equal and not equal operators. However, when I modify the formula to lets say, divide the number field by 2, I can filter using the equal and not equal operators.

For example:
Field 1 -> SomeNumberField__c: .8
Field 2 -> FormulaPercent__c: SomeNumberField__c

Querying the object by Id shows that FormulaPercent__c is 80, however when using the SOQL query: SELECT Id, [Other Fields] FROM CustomObject__c WHERE FormulaPercent__c = 80 returns no results.
Correspondingly, SELECT Id, [Other Fields] FROM CustomObject__c WHERE FormulaPercent__c = .8 also returns no result.

Is there a reason for this? And are there any workarounds to solve this issue?

I tried dividing by 100 to get the decimal representation of the percentage and got no result. Also tried querying with the whole number representation of the percentage and got no result.
I did find that other operators like greater than and less than will work.

Comment: Can you share the formula field you are creating with == and != operators. You might need to check the data types of the fields you are retrieving from the SOQL.